How to send effectively a list of WooCommerce Member emails to an external API endpoint?
I am using WooCommerce Subscriptions. I've recently been experimenting trying to send my Active, Pending Cancellation, and Complementary WooCommerce Members to an external API endpoint with one of our partners, but unfortunately the code I use in a WordPress Code Snippet doesn't seem to be working and isn't throwing any error, so nothing on the logs for me to debug despite me having the parameters enabled for debugging to take place.
It's also important to note that I've tested the API endpoint and Auth with Postmaster directly and it sends data absolutely fine through that so it must be something to do with a deficiency in my code or how my WordPress/WooCommerce is setup.
Here is the related code (the endpoint URL and Auth token removed for privacy purposes):
// Hook into the WooCommerce Memberships event when a user membership is updated or created. 
add_action('wc_memberships_user_membership_saved', 'send_membership_email_to_external', 10, 1);

// Function to handle real-time sync when membership is saved
function send_membership_email_to_external($user_membership) {
    // Ensure the passed object is of the correct type
    if (!($user_membership instanceof WC_Memberships_User_Membership)) {
        error_log('Unexpected object type in send_membership_email_to_external');
        return;
    }
    // Get user details
    $user_id = $user_membership->get_user_id();
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $user_email = $user_info->user_email;

    // Get the membership status
    $membership_status = $user_membership->get_status();

    // Check if the membership is 'wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel', or 'wc-complementary'
    if (in_array($membership_status, array('wc-active', 'wc-pending-cancel', 'wc-complementary'))) {
        // Proceed to sync the email to the API
        sync_emails_to_api(array($user_email));
    }
}

// Function to sync emails to the API
function sync_emails_to_api($email_array) {
    // Set the API endpoint and auth token
    $api_url = 'exampleurl.php';
    $auth_token = 'exampleauthtoken'; // Your provided auth token

    // Prepare the data to send
    $api_body = array(
        'action'      => 'departmentEmails', // As specified by the API docs
        'arrayEmails' => $email_array,       // Emails to sync
    );

    // Set up the request arguments
    $args = array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'headers'   => array(
            'Authorization' => $auth_token,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        ),
        'body'      => json_encode($api_body),
        'timeout'   => 45,
    );

    // Send the request using wp_remote_post()
    $response = wp_remote_post($api_url, $args);

    // Check for errors
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        // Log the error for debugging purposes
        error_log('API Sync Error: ' . $response->get_error_message());
    } else {
        // Optionally, handle the API response
        $api_response = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), true);
        if (isset($api_response['success']) && $api_response['success']) {
            // Successful sync (you can log this if needed)
            error_log('API Sync Success');
        } else {
            // Handle an unsuccessful response from the API
            error_log('API Sync Failed: ' . wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
        }
    }
}


I wonder if the code isn't working or it isn't being triggered? If I was you I would add some logging .. e.g. file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/debug.txt', "some useful text"\n", FILE_APPEND);
And then add that to a few places in your code and then you can at least see if what you think should be happening is indeed happening

For stuff like this I always first write it so that there's a manual trigger, like button, somewhere in the back end so I can make sure that the function works before I start automating it.  Have you tried that?
